# Bayer Image Viewer/Converter

Tags: viewer, images, conversion

I have raw Bayer images obtained from a camera sensor. There are 4 types of bayer image data formats:- GRBG, GBRG, BGGR, & RGGB. Each sample being 16 bit unsigned value.

I am looking for :-

1]Some image viewer to view images in such bayer data formats.

2]Converter to convert between above mentioned 4 bayer data format images.

thank you.

-AD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[dcraw](http://www.cybercom.net/~dcoffin/dcraw/) would be a good starting point. It will convert a huge range of raw formats to standard image formats, suitable for viewing and post-processing. It's mainly a source code distribution but there are links to executables for a range of platforms.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I downloaded dcraw executable for windows. But i have a x64 bit Windows-7. The dcraw executable is not running in it. Any pointers?

Comment: @goldenmean: Are you getting an error message or is nothing happening? `dcraw` needs to be run from the Command Prompt.

Comment: I ran it from command prompt. But even there this x64 compatibility error comes up.

Comment: @goldenmean: The 64 bit version on the following page works fine on my Win 7 x64 system. http://www.rawness.es/dcraw/?lang=en

Comment: I hadn't tried the x64 version although i had got it. It works for me as well. Thanks.